# Calculating screen intersection points with lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computer-science

I am writing a game and for the life of me can't figure out the most efficient way to program this. I have a boss who comes into the middle of the screen. He then engages 4 lasers which extend well off the screen. These lasers rotate. What I need to is to get the point of intersection of the laser and the screen edge. Here is what I am after.

[image: a crappy mockup]

Does anyone have a useful formula for me. It's been ages since I took a math class but I know I need slope starting from the middle of the screen using the angle of each laser and solving for where x and y are the screen extents. Can anyone give me a quick refresher? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use segment intersection between each laser an each screen edge. The equation of a line determined by the points (x1,y1) (x2,y2)
$ \begin{vmatrix}
x & y & 1  \\ 
x1 & y1 & 1 \\
x2 & y2 & 1 
\end{vmatrix} $ = 0; After you find the two equations, you simply solve the sistem composed by them. If the lines intersect (eq. they are not parallel) you should find only one point (xi,yi). Now you should check if this point is located on the edges of the screen, thus beaucase you calculated the intersection of the lines, not the segments. There is the posibility that the lines intersect but the segments not.

Comment: Can you show me an example of where to plug the numbers. What if I already have the slope? Thank you.

Comment: You have pixels. Therse are coordinates. You simply put them in the determinant and calculate the equation of the line. Have you tryed to write down something?